# MongoDb aggregate check if id exists in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have written this aggregate and it works fine

```
db.ParcelStatus.aggregate([{
     {
         $lookup: {
             from: "Parcel",
             localField: "parcelId",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "parcel"
         }
     },
     {
         $unwind: {
             path: "$parcel",
             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
         }
     },
     {
         $lookup: {
             from: "ParcelStatus",
             localField: "parcel._id",
             foreignField: "parcelId",
             as: "parcel.parcelStatuses"
         }
     },
     {
         $lookup: {
             from: "Customer",
             localField: "parcel.customerData.customerId",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "parcel.customerData.customer"
         }
     },
     {
         $unwind: "$parcel.customerData.customer"
     }
 ])
```

Now in ParcelStatus array that is INCLUDED inside PARCEL object i need to check that

```
if(parcel.ParcelStatus.includes((x) => x.statusRepositoryId === 'ID's from frontend')
//then run $match on root against statusRepositoryId === 'SPECIFIC STATIC ID'
```

I don't know how i can do that inside aggregate. Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: You may post the document structure on which to apply the condition.

Comment: @prasad_  you can consider this simple object in parcelStatus `{id: '_id', statusRepositoryId:'statusId', parcelId:'parcel id'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this `$match` stage:

```
{
    $match: {
        "parcel.parcelStatuses.statusRepositoryId": {$in: idArrayFromClient}
    }
}
```

Comment: this match stage needs to be inside lookup or in start?

Comment: Hey tom, thanks agains for your answer but i am unable to figure out where i need to fix this stage, would you be kind enough to write full aggregate? also is this a right way `parcel.parcelStatuses.statusRepositoryId`? parcelStatuses is array and not object so i am not sure if i can access statusrepositoryId inside parcelStatuses array like this

Comment: Just add this stage to the very end. (or after the lookup that retrieves the repositroy id). The syntax is correct, it's the behaviour of Mongo's dot notation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation